# How to add a form control-optionbutton in VBA (not ActiveX-optionbutton)?

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button, activex, form-control

I need to know how to add Form control optionbuttons to a WorkSheet by VBA. So far I've only managed to add ActiveX controls, which behave differently.

I'm building an Excel 365 form (on a WorkSheet, not a VBA UserForm) including several groups of radiobuttons/optionbuttons. I see that I can add two kinds of optionnbuttons: Form controls and ActiveX controls.
Both controls can be linked to a cell, but return different results:
Form controls return a number as a result
ActiveX controls return TRUE or FALSE

I can add a optionbutton to my sheet using this code:

```
With FormSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Optionbutton.1")
    .Left = 10
end with
```

I was hoping to get Form Controls, but as far as I can see the created controls are ActiveX controls. When I add a .LinkedCell, they return Boolean values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmpf...

```
Dim OptBtn As OptionButton
Set OptBtn = ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(580.5, 48.75, 72, 72)
```

seems to do the trick.